# Using command line how to open a specific section of GUI System Preferences?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

It is possible to open a specific section (sub section) of the GUI System Preferences via command line terminal?

Example:
If I want to open just the main System Preferences window, I just run `open /Applications/System\ Preferences.app/` but what about (for example) I want to open the **System Preferences > Security and Privacy** section?

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to know where the actual PreferencePane resides. Just supply the full path to the section you want.

For Apple supplied PreferencePanes it's easy:

```
open /System/Library/PreferencePanes/Security.prefPane
```

opens your desired System Preferences > Security and Privacy.

Other preferencePanes might be found at `/Library/PreferencePanes` or `~/Library/PreferencePanes`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal pane "Security\n& Privacy"
end tell
```

In the shell, you'll need to wrap this inside an `osascript` command. The best solution will depend on what your exact workflow is, e.g. whether you want to do this as part of a script.