# Using the command-line / Terminal, is it possible to determine if this Mac has Touch ID or not?

Tags: terminal, bash, zsh, system-information, system-profiler

I am trying to find a way, using the Terminal/command line, to determine if the Mac I am using has Touch ID or not.

So far web searches have not turned up any answers.

I would have thought that either `ioreg` or `system_profiler` might have the answer, but my attempts to use them have not uncovered anything useful.

(I did find one reference to *Multitouch ID* but I believe that has to do with the *trackpad* not Touch ID.)

Answer (score 1):

- You can also look for hardware info and match it against apple provided info about Touch ID enabled Macs.

  > Only the 2016, 2017 and 2018 MacBook Pros with "Touch Bar" have Touch ID.

  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8597511 Though a more credible and updated source would be better.
- Also,  If system pref > Touch ID exists, this can be an indicator.

  - [Using command line how to open a specific section of GUI System Preferences?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366222/using-command-line-how-to-open-a-specific-section-of-gui-system-preferences)
  - [How do you access network preferences from the Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65794/how-do-you-access-network-preferences-from-the-terminal)
- https://ioshacker.com/how-to/use-touch-id-for-sudo-in-terminal-on-mac look for `tid` (I don't know where)

Comment: Thanks. The first bullet point might be an option. The second is not. `/System/Library/PreferencePanes/TouchID.prefPane` exists in versions of macOS which supports Touch ID even if the hardware does not. (Confirmed on my Macs, running 10.13, 10.14, and 10.15 even on hardware that doesn't support Touch ID I think the last one is just about setting up Touch ID to work with sudo.

Comment: the argument it gives to allow Touch ID for sudo might be connected to something else, idk

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and found the build-in tool `bioutil` to be the solution.

MacBook with Touch ID:

```
~ bioutil -r
User Touch ID configuration:
Touch ID for unlock: 1
Touch ID for ApplePay: 1
Effective Touch ID for unlock: 1
Effective Touch ID for ApplePay: 1
Operation performed successfully.
```

Mac Pro without Touch ID

```
~ bioutil -r
User Touch ID configuration:
Operation performed successfully.
```

Answer (score -1):

Google shows some hits which I can't verify because I don't have access to a Mac with TouchID currently:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print :$(sysctl -n hw.model):_LOCALIZABLE_:description" /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ServerInformation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/English.lproj/SIMachineAttributes.plist | grep -oc "Touch ID"
```

> It will return 1 if touch id is available and 0 if not

One further method can be found in the same thread: [TouchID Extension Attribute](https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/27541/touchid-extension-attribute)

Comment: Thank you. However, I can confirm that this does _not_ work on my 2018 MacBook Air (which does have Touch ID), so I would say this is not a viable answer.

Comment: @TJLuoma At least it works the other way round: I get a `0` for my iMac...;-)